# PHP's current() & key() functions; inconsistent with function signature

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

I've noticed that PHP's [`current()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [`key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) array functions (*like other array-pointer functions*) take the array argument by reference:

> mixed **current** ( array *&$array* )
>   Every array has an internal pointer to its "current" element, which is initialized to the first element inserted into the array.

After a few quick checks, it appears that both `current()` and `key()` (*unlike other array-pointer functions*) accept the array argument by value, thereby not throwing an error when passed the return value of a function.

I've concluded that it's simply because `current()` and `key()` do not try to move the array pointer, and therefore do not require the argument be passed by reference (*or do so in some transparent, quiet, secretive way*). However, this is of a bit of concern to me.

Can anyone confirm if this is the intended functionality? I'd gladly use it to snatch up the first element/key of a returned array, but it seems awfully strange that PHP is allowing this when under nearly any other circumstance a fatal error (*or strict standards warning*) is issued for passing values to a by-reference parameter.

Feature or bug?

---

For instance:

```
error_reporting(-1);

function getArray(){
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
}

var_dump( current(getArray()) );
var_dump( key(getArray())     );
var_dump( next(getArray())    );
var_dump( prev(getArray())    );
var_dump( reset(getArray())   );
var_dump( end(getArray())     );
```

Results:

```
string(1) "a"

int(0)

Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference ...
string(1) "b"

Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference ...
bool(false)

Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference ...
string(1) "a"

Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference ...
string(1) "c"
```

Comment: @ajreal - No, the first `array` is merely a type-hint. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php for comparison.

Comment: @ajreal - Perhaps I'm not understanding, but the `array &$array` parameter listing (*so far as I know*) is indicative of a required array by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely a feature, and I would not want to live without it.

Now the question is if the documentation is correct about the `&`.

## The code

### current

```
PHP_FUNCTION(current)
{
    HashTable *array;
    zval **entry;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "H", &array) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (zend_hash_get_current_data(array, (void **) &entry) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    RETURN_ZVAL(*entry, 1, 0);
}
```

### next

```
PHP_FUNCTION(next)
{
    HashTable *array;
    zval **entry;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "H", &array) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    zend_hash_move_forward(array);

    if (return_value_used) {
        if (zend_hash_get_current_data(array, (void **) &entry) == FAILURE) {
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }

        RETURN_ZVAL(*entry, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

## Conclusion

The docs are correct - the array is taken as reference in both cases.

No idea though why on throws the error, the other not.

Btw, the errors are thrown in

- Zend/zend_vm_def.h
- Zend/zend_vm_execute.h

Comment: Thanks @cweiske - That's not what I'm on about though. I'm not explicitly passing arguments by reference. I'll edit for clarity, check in a second.

Comment: Thanks @cweiske - That's very strange (*I concluded similarly, merely watching memory allocation to PHP when passing an enormous hash map to `current()`; it didn't double*) How peculiar. I'm going to file something. A bug in docs, or whatnot. Thanks again though cweiske, I appreciate your help and persistence.

Comment: This answer isn't exactly true. The codes shown do not have to do with references. References are handled in the arginfo structs for the respective functions. E.g. for current(): http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#291 As you can see it uses PREFER_REF, so it will behave reference-y if it can, but will also accepts non-references.