# PHP core function arguments; manual says reference, however it accepts values

Tags: php, function-signature

I've noticed some inconsistencies in the PHP manual; a number of core function signatures are documented to accept arguments by reference, however they accept arguments by value.

I posted a more [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992359/phps-current-key-functions-inconsistent-with-function-signature) previously, and @cweiske provided a great answer (*with reference to the pertinent PHP source*) however these inconsistencies appear to be more rampant.

There are a number of functions that are affected by this (*I'll update this list as warrants; also note, these tests were done in an `error_reporting(-1)` environment*)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

  - This was already discussed at the linked question
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

  - This was already discussed at the linked question
- <strike>http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php</strike>

  - <strike>`array` **`array_replace_recursive`** `( array` *`&$array`* `, array` *`&$array1`* `[, array` *`&$`*`... ] )`</strike>
  - Accepts arguments `$array`, `$array1`, etc., by value. **This has been corrected.**
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

  - `bool` **`array_multisort`** `( array` *`&$arr`* `[, mixed` *`$arg`* `=` *`SORT_ASC`* `[, mixed` *`$arg`* `=` *`SORT_REGULAR`* `[, mixed` *`$`*`... ]]] )`
  - Accepts arguments `$arr`, etc., by value. This **should** throw an error, as it won't do anything if the argument isn't a variable.

Now I'm concerned, not because I'm being anal about the documentation, but because I fear that PHP devs are on the fence about the implementation details of these functions (*or something equally unreliable*)

I use `array_replace_recursive()` for instance, to take an array argument, and apply it against another array containing defaults. Some of my codebase has taken advantage of this inconsistency, to simply do:

```
$values = array_replace_recursive(array(
    'setting_1' => array(
        'sub-setting_1' => '',
        'sub-setting_2' => '',
        'sub-setting_3' => '',
     ),
    'setting_2' => array(
        'sub-setting_1' => 0,
        'sub-setting_2' => 0,
     ),
     'setting_3' => true,
), $values);
```

Thus producing a properly formatted array (*to get around gratuitous `isset()` calls*)

Should I be concerned with this? I'm thinking about submitting a documentation related bug request, but I'm first curious if anyone on SO (*looking in your direction @cweiske*) has insight on **why** this has been done.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your dilemma, but those functions don't directly modify the data in their parameters, so whether they accept via reference or value is sort of a moot point isn't it? Either way you're going to need to assign the return value if you want the function call to actually **do** anything for you.

In terms of insight into **why** you might be seeing the discrepancy. PHP 5 has had many changes made to the way references work. In fact I believe it's PHP 5.3+ that no longer permits certain usages of & to assign by reference. What you may be seeing is the transition of some of the PHP core functions to comply with the new rules about reference assignment. If memory serves me, PHP 5.3 branch was actually intended to be PHP 6, but was decidedly merged into the trunk as a branch instead of waiting for several complex features to be finished. This would account for why you've never seen confusion like this before in PHP.

Comment: Thanks @Brian - My dilemma, is that the point isn't moot for the fact that the PHP devs may have explicitly documented this because there is change on the horizon. If the function *doesn't* modify the arguments, then why define them by reference? If the function *does* modify the arguments, then why accept passed values? If this is an documentation oversight, and with 5.4, along with all the version changes/branching, (*as you mentioned; 5.3, 6.0, etc.*) then it's completely understandable. However the implementation permits passing values. This doesn't seem right, and I just want to know why.

Comment: Ah I see where you're going with that lol your concern then is if they intend to modify the way these functions work by allowing them to take their parameters as references and directly work on them rather than requiring the result of the function to be returned? I could see how that could be an issue :P Unfortunately I'm also not someone who commonly delves into PHP's source, so I'll leave the fielding of the question to one of the nerdier nerds here on stack ;)